# Panda Numpy converting data to a column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a data result that when I print it looks like

```
  >>>print(result)

   [[0]
    [1]
    [0]
    [0]
    [1]
    [0]]
```

I guess that's about the same  as [ [0][1][0][0][1][0] ] which seems a bit weird [0,1,0,0,1,0] seems a more logical representation but somehow it's not like that.

Though I would like these values to be added as a single column to a Panda dataframe df

I tried several ways to join it to my dataframe:

```
 df = pd.concat(df,result)
 df = pd.concat(df,{'result' =result})
 df['result'] =pd.aply(result, axis=1)
```

with no luck. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is multiple ways for flatten your data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.rand(6,2))

result = np.array([0,1,0,0,1,0])[:, None]
print (result)
[[0]
 [1]
 [0]
 [0]
 [1]
 [0]]


df['result'] = result[:,0]
df['result1'] = result.ravel()
#df['result1'] = np.concatenate(result)

print (df)
          0         1  result  result1
0  0.098767  0.933861       0        0
1  0.532177  0.610121       1        1
2  0.288742  0.718452       0        0
3  0.520980  0.367746       0        0
4  0.253658  0.011994       1        1
5  0.662878  0.846113       0        0
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to put that array in flat format pandas dataframe column, following is simplest way:

`df["result"] = sum(result, [])`

Answer (score 0):

As long as the number of data points in this list is the same as the number of rows of the dataframe this should work:

```
import pandas as pd

your_data = [[0],[1],[0],[0],[1],[0]]

df = pd.DataFrame() # skip and use your own dataframe with len(df) == len(your_data)
df['result'] = [i[0] for i in your_data]
```